# Bindig List to ListView in XAML not working?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have read all the similar posts but did not found a solution for my problem.

I have the following List:

```
private List<Character> _Characters;

public List<Character> Characters
{
    get { return _Characters; }
    set { Set(ref _Characters, value);}
}
```

As I debugged the code, all the items (around 500) are added to the list properly.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Characters: " FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=name}" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" Margin="12" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

However, when I run the program, the names are not displayed at all.

**EDIT: Datacontext is set in the XAML:**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Comment: How and where do you set the DataContext for your view? Does your Character class have a public name property?

Comment: Yes it has a public name property. I also edited the post, including how I set the data context.

Comment: Try to use ObservableCollection instead of List

Comment: Using Observable collection works, thank you!

Comment: I will post as answer, so you can mark it, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ObservableCollection instead of List

```
private ObservableCollection<Character> _Characters;

public ObservableCollection<Character> Characters
{
    get { return _Characters; }
    set { Set(ref _Characters, value);}
}
```

also give a look at https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged